# Unable to install therubyracer gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, installation, therubyracer

I installed **libv8** gem seperately without a hitch, but when I try to install therubyracer gem I get the following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing therubyracer:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... yes
Warning! Unable to load libv8 ~> 3.16.14.
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
    --with-pthreadlib
    --without-pthreadlib
    --enable-debug
    --disable-debug
extconf.rb:32:in `<main>': undefined method `configure_makefile' for Libv8:Module (NoMethodError)


Gem files will remain installed in /home/thecodehitman/ruby/gems/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/thecodehitman/ruby/gems/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1/ext/v8/gem_make.out
```

Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ sudo gem install therubyracer --platform ruby
```

Try with or without sudo.

If it is a Ruby on Rails app, include the line:

```
gem 'therubyracer', :platform=>:ruby
```

inside Gemfile.

Comment: Sadly, since this is a shared server I don't have sudo priviledges, but it didn't work without sudo.

Comment: Is it a Ruby on Rails app?

Comment: if that is not possible, pls try to remove the Gemfile.lock and then ruby with --no-deployment.